# Is there a way to wait for Google sheets to finish calculating before performing batchGet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am currently using the Python google-api-python-client to access Sheets API v4 in order to read & write data to a worksheet.

This worksheet results in 40 rows of data all of which heavily rely on multiple iterative calculations. Writing the data via API works as intended, however, it appears that calling `batchGet` reads values from the sheet prior to the sheet finishing it's calculation.

This results in read values that are simply incorrect and inaccurate. Is there any way to ensure that the worksheet finishes calculating before reading the data?

Comment: When the values are put to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API and the calculation is started, the cell displays `Loading...`. At this time, when the values from the ranges, which are calculating, are retrieved by Sheets API, the values are not retrieved until the calculation is finished. But in your question, you say that the progressing values are retrieved. If it's so, how about the following workaround?

Comment: As a workaround, I would like to propose to use a custom function for waiting like `function wait(ms) {Utilities.sleep(ms); return; }`. When you use this, please put the value like `=wait(10000)` as a formula. When this is put, Sheets API doesn't retrieve the values until the count of 10 seconds is finished. In order to recalculate the custom function, it is required to change `10000` of `=wait(10000)` like `=wait(10001)`. Please be careful this. I posted this as a comment because I'm not sure whether this is the workaround for your issue. If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike - this doesn't guarantee a good result. Iterative calculations are handled different in gSheets than a long "Loading...", iterative calculations perform, finish and then perform again until a steady state is found. I believe that is precisely the issue here - that the api response triggers after a single loop rather than at the steady state. Delaying X amount of seconds may help, but if the loops take longer than the delay, your result is still off...

Comment: @ZAR Thank you for replying. I apologize my proposal was not useful. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. If you think my comments should be deleted, please tell me. I would like to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gSheet API doesn't "return early", but it is possible that the values in your sheet are intermediate values mid iterative calculation.

gSheets have a maximum iterative calculation limit, which you can set in:

> File > Spreadsheet Settings > Calculation > Max number of iterations

Whatever the state of the sheet is by the final iteration are the values that will be returned by the gSheet API.

As you point out, this can lead to the results having intermediate or "half" values.

---

## How to solve iterative calculations returning intermediate values.

### Example

A potential solution is to reformat some of your spreadsheet calculations to ensure that final values are resolved by the gSheet interpreter at the same iterative tick.

For instance, say we have the following spreadsheet:

```
  |      A      |                    B                       | C |           D  
1 | fruit_input | =if(fruit_input = "", "", IMPORTRANGE(...))|   | =vlookup(A1,B:C,2)
```

`A1` is our input from the API. We're hoping to get the value from `D1`.

When we input a value into `A1`, `B1` evaluates to `True` and imports a range (of prices, perhaps). `D1` then performs a lookup of `B:C`, searching for the fruit from `a1` and returning the value in col C (returning from th importrange).

This may look like a single line of operations, but it is actually two different iterations. If you have iterative calculations turned off, or too low (or they run out), you'll have a blank return value from `D2`, even though when you visit the spreadsheet directly, you see values in `B:C`.

A quick way to diagnose this is when you're in the spreadsheet, try editing a single blank cell, which will cause th spreadsheet to recalculate. The importrange won't trigger again, but I bet there is now a value in `D2`.

### Solution

One way to force gSheets to include the calculation of `D2` into the first iteration is to add an IF statement wrapper, like so:

```
|               D              |
|=if(B1="","",vlookup(A1,B:C,2)|
```

by including the IF wrapper, you force google sheets to include the formula in `D1` onto the same iteration, the same call stack as `B1`, and then the sheet will not resolve until `B1` and then `D1` resolve.