# Does Google Sheet API v4 gets the final result until calculation (non-circular) is completed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I am writing a chat-bot to sent data to google sheet. Then retrieves a calculated data back and dump it to the chat app.

[Is there a way to wait for Google sheets to finish calculating before performing batchGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314924/is-there-a-way-to-wait-for-google-sheets-to-finish-calculating-before-performing)

According to this post, Google Sheet API v4 does not get a value until the iteration is complete.

My question is that:

The above post discuss a scenario where formula 2 gets result depending on formula 1 and formula 1 gets result depending on a constant cell (non reference). It actually isn't an circular reference where it based the calculation of its own result.

From my understanding, iterative calculation is for circular references.

My sheet does not have circular references but do have quite heavy multi-reference calculation. Therefore, I should not be getting any intermediate values mid iterative calculation.

So if I set **Iterative calculation** to **OFF** and **Recalculation** to **ON** will the API gets the final value?

Or, will it returns any previous result?

Haven't actually tried the API yet, but while using browser the result cell does stop at the previous value until the progression bar at the top right corner finish loading when data is changed.

If previous result may be the case, are there any workarounds other than the if-method? If if-method is the only work around, must I added it to all intermediate function?

Comment: `So if I set Iterative calculation to OFF and Recalculation to ON will the API gets the final value?` Why don't you test and see?

Comment: I tested a few so far haven't run into the case I predicted. However, I would still like to know the exact answer of how the API works.

Comment: I suggest in this case applying to work for Google's Sheets API team, as it's not public and SO users won't be able to help you there. You can only test what is available. Remember SO is a programming Q&A forum and not a team of testers you can call upon - test yourself, post your findings and ask specific questions as to where you have become stuck.